# Property 'ethereum' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis' in Next Typescript project

Tags: ethers.js, typescript

I'm trying to use ethers in a Next/Typescript project:

code:

```
if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {}
```

Error:

```
Property 'ethereum' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'
```

I have tried to extend the Window interface in my next-env.d.ts file but the error persists.

next-env.d.ts:

```
/// <reference types="next" />
/// <reference types="next/image-types/global" />

// NOTE: This file should not be edited
// see https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript for more information.
declare global {
  interface Window {
    ethereum: any
  }
}
```

Is there a specific fix for Next.js?

Answer (score 2):

The next file should not be edited - you can create another declaration file like `globals.d.ts` with this content:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    ethereum: any
  }
}
```

and it should work

Comment: Somehow that does not work. I declared it inside the file that gives me TS warning